# Is it better to return NULL or empty values from functions/methods where the return value is not present?

Tags: object-oriented, design-patterns, architecture, object-oriented-design

I am looking for a recommendation here.  I am struggling with whether it is better to return NULL or an empty value from a method when the return value is not present or cannot be determined.

Take the following two methods as an examples:

```cpp
string ReverseString(string stringToReverse) // takes a string and reverses it.
Person FindPerson(int personID)    // finds a Person with a matching personID.
```

In `ReverseString()`, I would say return an empty string because the return type is string, so the caller is expecting that.  Also, this way, the caller would not have to check to see if a NULL was returned.

In `FindPerson()`, returning NULL seems like a better fit.  Regardless of whether or not NULL or an empty Person Object (`new Person()`) is returned the caller is going to have to check to see if the Person Object is NULL or empty before doing anything to it (like calling `UpdateName()`).  So why not just return NULL here and then the caller only has to check for NULL.

Does anyone else struggle with this?  Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: It will vary. You could also argue that the method should stop values which are incorrect up front, for instance your stringToReverse parameter being passed in as empty or null. If you performed that check (threw back an exception), it will always return something other than null.

Comment: Fowler POEAA - p. 496 Base Patterns - Special Case(null object)  Bloch Effective Java, 2nd Edition Item 43: Return empty arrays or collections, not nulls

Comment: @Boris I didn't see your comment. I actually just posted Special Case as an answer.

Comment: @Thomas I don't see any problem in it :). As for the question it's a matter of common sense anyway.

Comment: An interesting comment is that in Oracle databases NULL and the empty string are the same

Comment: be consistent. Always returns nulls, A string can be null'ed so you want to expose this to your user and it their responsibility to check for nulls. You can't unforutently apply that to native types like int and long but you can if you used the ? keyword. So Int? but it just makes things really weird.

Comment: Depends on your team consensus: in the case of mine, we agreed to return `null` for method that returns a single object indicating a value is not found. For method that return multiple objects (list, enumerable, array), we return `empty list of object`. It's all about consistency and convention.

Comment: IMO, If *find person by id* semantically maps to a *get person by id*, I would throw an exception because it is expected to find a customer given an id is known to exist. If you've heard the phrase "Caller's data, caller's problem" which is indicative that the caller provided an invalid id therefore we don't return to say no data is available. On the other hand if it maps to a *search for person by id*, it would be reasonable to return to no data found i.e: `null` because now the caller is asking if it exists as opposed to give me something I know exists.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

StackOverflow has a good discussion about this exact topic in this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626597/should-functions-return-null-or-an-empty-object). In the top rated question, kronoz notes:

> Returning null is usually the best idea if you intend to indicate that
> no data is available.
>
> An empty object implies data has been returned, whereas returning null
> clearly indicates that nothing has been returned.
>
> Additionally, returning a null will result in a null exception if you
> attempt to access members in the object, which can be useful for
> highlighting buggy code - attempting to access a member of nothing
> makes no sense. Accessing members of an empty object will not fail
> meaning bugs can go undiscovered.

Personally, I like to return empty strings for functions that return strings to minimize the amount of error handling that needs to be put in place. However, you'll need to make sure that the group that your working with will follow the same convention - otherwise the benefits of this decision won't be achieved.

However, as the poster in the SO answer noted, nulls should probably be returned if an object is expected so that there is no doubt about whether data is being returned.

In the end, there's no single best way of doing things. Building a team consensus will ultimately drive your team's best practices.

Comment: _Personally, I like to return empty strings for functions that return strings to minimize the amount of error handling that needs to be put in place._ Never understood this argument. The null check is what, at most < 10 chars? Why do we act like this is back bending labor?

Comment: Not to mention that some languages will do it for you ("?." in Groovy, IIRC)

Comment: Nobody said it was back bending labor. But it *is* labor. It adds a special case to the code which means one more branch to test. Plus, it disrupts the flow of the code. `for x in list_of_things() {...}` is arguably quicker to grok then `l = list_of_things(); if l != null {...}`

Comment: @Bryan: there is a big difference between an empty list of values, and an empty string.  A string seldom represents a list of characters.

Comment: @kevin cline: of course. But in the case of a string, you may want that string to appear in a log whether it's null or not. Having to check if it's null so you can print an empty string obfuscates the real intent. Or perhaps it's something like database field that contains user-contributed content that you want to add to a web page. It's easier to do `emit(user.hometown)` than `if user.hometown == null { emit("")  else {emit(user.hometown)}`

Comment: Not only is it extra typing (not a big deal), but it affects readability. I personally find code with a bunch of null checks distracting.

Comment: @AaronMcIver: It's only 10 chars... _every time you call it._  Now, if you're a fan of AOP, there are some very nice ways to solve this problem.

Comment: How about when you are returning a guid? An empty guid is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. Should an api return null or 000... ? I would say it should return 000...

Comment: return optional instead.

Comment: For strings, would an empty string be a valid result? Say you return given name and family name. Null indicates not found (some error), but given name or family name can very rarely be an empty string.

Answer (score 102):

In all the code I write, I avoid returning `null` from a function.  I read that in [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.ca/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882).

The problem with using `null` is that the person using the interface doesn't know if `null` is a possible outcome, and whether they have to check for it, because there's no `not null` reference type.

In F# you can return an `option` type, which can be `some(Person)` or `none`, so it's obvious to the caller that they have to check.

The analogous C# (anti-)pattern is the `Try...` method:

```csh
public bool TryFindPerson(int personId, out Person result);
```

Now I know people have said they *hate* the `Try...` pattern because having an output parameter breaks the ideas of a pure function, but it's really no different than:

```csh
class FindResult<T>
{
   public FindResult(bool found, T result)
   {
       this.Found = found;
       this.Result = result;
   }

   public bool Found { get; private set; }
   // Only valid if Found is true
   public T Result { get; private set;
}

public FindResult<Person> FindPerson(int personId);
```

...and to be honest you can assume that *every* .NET programmer knows about the `Try...` pattern because it's used internally by the .NET framework.  That means they *don't have to read the documentation* to understand what it does, which is more important to me than sticking to some purist's view of functions (understanding that `result` is an `out` parameter, not a `ref` parameter).

So I'd go with `TryFindPerson` because you seem to indicate it's perfectly normal to be unable to find it.

If, on the other hand, there's no logical reason that the caller would ever provide a `personId` that didn't exist, I would probably do this:

```csh
public Person GetPerson(int personId);
```

...and then I'd throw an exception if it was invalid.  The `Get...` prefix implies that the caller knows it should succeed.

Comment: +1. Some languages don't even allow nulls and use option types only.

Comment: +1, I would answer this question with a reference to Clean Code if you hadn't already done so. I like the mantra: "IF YOUR FUNCTION CANT DO WHAT IT'S NAME SAYS, THEN THROW AN EXCEPTION." Muuuch better than checking for null every dozen lines or so....

Comment: *"...and to be honest you can assume that every .NET programmer knows about the `Try...` pattern"*, I envy the utopia you must work in...

Comment: @Chad - I said you "can assume".  I meant that in the same way you can assume they all know to use the `StringBuilder` class when concatenating strings inside of a loop.  :)

Comment: I've given up assuming anything about the knowledge of people.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock Wait what? I'm supposed to use a `StringBuilder` instead of `+` ?

Comment: "The problem with using null is that the person using the interface doesn't know if null is a possible outcome, and whether they have to check for it, because there's no not null reference type."

Since reference types can be null, can't you always assume that null is a possible outcome?

Comment: I use a mixed approach; depending on whether I'm debugging or deploying, I either make sure what is returned will lead to an error as early and violently as possible when used improperly (so my debugger triggers), or I return something that attempts to keep the broken component running.

Comment: If a function returns a pointer (C / C++) or a reference to an object (Java), I always assume that it may return null.

Comment: "The problem with using null is that the person using the interface doesn't know if null is a possible outcome, and whether they have to check for it, [...]" If a method might return null, it should be explicitly mentioned as part of the API contract.

Comment: @ZsoltTörök - who wants to re-check the documentation every time you make a method call?  Better to make it obvious that it *does not* if it really won't, to make life easier on the users of your API (which could also be you, months or years later).

Comment: @ScottWhitlock: of course every API designer should keep the principle of least surprise in mind and strive for simplicity. However, if API users don't bother to check the documentation, they only have themselves to blame.

Comment: I am not sure about this advice, why all the hassle? Get -> must succeed or it throws exception. Find -> automatically expresses uncertainty of existence so null is possible outcome. And you still have pure function...

Comment: @Giorgio... I agree completely. Also, I am not sure, if .NET languages or Java know how to optimize an "option" type. Assuming they are not, checking for null is way faster and less resource consuming option.

Comment: *The problem with using null is that the person using the interface doesn't know ifnull is a possible outcome*. There's something named **Documentation**

Comment: @Laiv - that's a really naïve thing to say.  The reason we follow patterns is to make it easy for people to use our stuff without reading documentation.  Writing an API is like designing a user interface, and one of the most popular user interface design books is titled "Don't Make me Think."  When possible, make it so nobody has to read the documentation.

Comment: Sorry but I think that doc is a must. To use frameworks (aka API aswell) would be a nightmare w.o documentation. Look at any framework you have used. Java, .Net does not matter. If it's a succesful framework/Api it has documentation for sure. Online, interactive, at code,... To document code and the whole project is the task most underated of software enginery. Often is a problem of time/money but then the money is spent in learning-curves. Sorry if I have sound rude, it was not my intention. Your answer is really good and I voted it. But it doesn't make doc less important.

Comment: One more thing. Patterns were made to don't reinvent the wheel over and over. Patterns gives quality to the project. Make it escalable and flexible. But patterns are noy any sort of replacement of documentation. That's not a good reason to let your code undocumented

Comment: @Laiv, one thing is to document a public API and another very different thing is to rely your code's readability on class comments and documentation, instead of making the actual code more readable.

Comment: I much prefer using throws if the language / compiler makes it obvious that the function throws. It is much clearer that something can go wrong and the function will not return what is expected. It can also detail exactly why it is unable to complete. Anyone else (even yourself in the future) who uses the function is warned you may not get what you expect. This is especially true is less common situations where you might never expose the null value until the program is deployed.

Comment: What a nonsense! `null` is a perfectly valid outcome in all cases, even if the function is able to do what its name states. Returning `null` and throwing are two different things and are not mutually exclusive!

Comment: In Swift, you can’t use the result of a function that can return nil without some check, and you can’t check the result of a function that cannot return nil. So the compiler will force you to do the right thing.

Answer (score 34):

You could try Martin Fowler's [Special Case pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/specialCase.html), from [Paterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321127420):

> Nulls are awkward things in object-oriented programs because they
>   defeat polymorphism. Usually you can invoke foo freely on a variable
>   reference of a given type without worrying about whether the item is
>   the exact type or a sub-class. With a strongly typed language you can
>   even have the compiler check that the call is correct. However, since
>   a variable can contain null, you may run into a runtime error by
>   invoking a message on null, which will get you a nice, friendly stack
>   trace.
>
> If it's possible for a variable to be null, you have to remember to
>   surround it with null test code so you'll do the right thing if a null
>   is present. Often the right thing is same in many contexts, so you end
>   up writing similar code in lots of places - committing the sin of code
>   duplication.
>
> Nulls are a common example of such problems and others crop up
>   regularly. In number systems you have to deal with infinity, which has
>   special rules for things like addition that break the usual invariants
>   of real numbers. One of my earliest experiences in business software
>   was with a utility customer who wasn't fully known, referred to as
>   "occupant." All of these imply altering the usual behavior of the
>   type.
>
> Instead of returning null, or some odd value, return a Special Case
>   that has the same interface as what the caller expects.

Comment: I ran into this scenario, but only after the software was released. My test data never triggered it, so it was a bit out of the blue and a pain to debug. Though I didn't solve it with the Special Case pattern, it's good to be aware of it.

Answer (score 19):

I would think `ReverseString()` would return the reversed string and it would throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if passed in a `Null`.

I think `FindPerson()` should follow the [NullObject Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) or raise an unchecked exception about not finding something if you should always be able to find something.

Having to deal with `Null` is something that should be avoided. Having `Null` in languages has been called a [Billion Dollar Mistake](http://qconlondon.com/london-2009/presentation/Null+References:+The+Billion+Dollar+Mistake) by it's inventor!

> I call it my billion-dollar mistake. It was the invention of the null
>   reference in 1965. At that time, I was designing the first
>   comprehensive type system for references in an object oriented
>   language (ALGOL W).
>
> My goal was to ensure that all use of references should be absolutely
>   safe, with checking performed automatically by the compiler. But I
>   couldn't resist the temptation to put in a null reference, simply
>   because it was so easy to implement.
>
> This has led to innumerable errors, vulnerabilities, and system
>   crashes, which have probably caused a billion dollars of pain and
>   damage in the last forty years.
>
> In recent years, a number of program analysers like PREfix and PREfast
>   in Microsoft have been used to check references, and give warnings if
>   there is a risk they may be non-null. More recent programming
>   languages like Spec# have introduced declarations for non-null
>   references. This is the solution, which I rejected in 1965.
>
> Tony Hoare

Answer (score 13):

Return an [Option](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aMaybe). All the benefits of returning a different invalid value (like being able to have empty values in your collections) without any risk of NullPointerException.

Comment: Interesting. How to implement an option in Java? And in C++?

Comment: @Giorgio, For Java, the Guava libraries, from Google, have a class called [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html).

Comment: For C++, there's `boost::optional<T>`

Answer (score 10):

I see both sides of this argument, and I realize some rather influential voices (e.g., Fowler) advocate not returning nulls in order to keep code clean, avoid extra error-handling blocks, etc.

However, I tend to side with proponents of returning null. I find there is an important distinction in invoking a method and it responding with *I don't have any data* and it responding with *I have this empty String*.

Since I've seen some of the discussion referencing a Person class, consider the scenario where you attempt to look up an instance of the class. If you pass in some finder attribute (e.g., an ID), a client can immediately check for null to see if no value was found. This is not necessarily exceptional (hence not needing exceptions), but it should also be documented clearly. Yes, this requires some rigor on the part of the client, and no, I don't think that's a bad thing at all.

Now consider the alternative where you return a valid Person object... that has nothing in it. Do you put nulls in all of its values (name, address, favoriteDrink), or do you now go populate those with valid but empty objects? How is your client to now determine that no actual Person was found? Do they need to check if the name is an empty String instead of null? Isn't this sort of thing actually going to lead to as much or more code clutter and conditional statements than if we'd just checked for null and moved on?

Again, there are points on either side of this argument I could agree with, but I find this makes the most sense to the most people (making the code more maintainable).

Comment: The difference is, "does `FindPerson` or `GetPerson` return a null or throw an exception if the key doesn't exist?"  As a user of the API I just *don't know* and I have to check the documentation.  On the other hand, `bool TryGetPerson(Guid key, out Person person)` doesn't require me to check the documentation and I *know* an exception isn't thrown in what amounts to a rather non-exceptional circumstance.  That's the point I'm trying to make in my answer.

Comment: I think people got too attached to exceptions. Exceptions are bad and resource consuming. Not to mention people do try and catch statements without resolving anything. Exceptions are clear sign that something went fundamentally wrong. For instance, null references throws an exception, because it is clearly wrong to reference null objects. It is wrong to use it to check if person was found or not.

Comment: @VladimirKocjancic: I totally agree: exceptions should be used for exceptional situation, like software bugs, hardware failures, system misconfiguration. If you are computing a partial function (like `findPerson`) it is absolutely normal to get back no result. This should not lead to an exception.

Answer (score 8):

Return null if you need to know if the item exists or not. Otherwise, return the expected data type. This is especially true if you're returning a list of items. It's usually safe to assume if the caller is wanting a list, they'll want to iterate over the list. Many (most? all?) languages fail if you try to iterate over null but not when you iterate over a list that is empty.

I find it frustrating to try and use code like this, only to have it fail:

```
for thing in get_list_of_things() {
    do_something_clever(thing)
}
```

I shouldn't have to add a special case for the case when there are no *things*.

Comment: In cases where a list or other group of values is expected, I always elect to return an empty list, for exactly this reason.  The default action (iterating across an empty list) is almost always right, and if it isn't then the caller can explicitly check to see if the list is empty.

Comment: In that case I return a list containing all items that it should return (which may be none), and null in case of an error.

Answer (score 7):

null is the best thing to return if and only if the following following conditions apply:

- the null result is **expected in normal operation**. It could be expected that you may not be able to find a person in some reasonable circumstances, so findPerson() returning null is fine. However if it is a genuinely unexpected failure (e.g. in a function called saveMyImportantData()) then you should be throwing an Exception. There's a hint in the name - Exceptions are for exceptional circumstances!
- null is used to mean **"not found / no value"**. If you mean something else, then return something else! Good examples would be floating point operations returning Infinity or NaN - these are values with specific meanings so it would get very confusing if you returned null here.
- The function is **meant to return a single value**, such as findPerson(). If it was designed to return a collection e.g. findAllOldPeople() then an empty collection is best. A corollary of this is that a function which returns a collection *should never return null*.

In addition, make sure that you **document the fact** that the function can return null.

If you follow these rules, nulls are mostly harmless. Note that if you forget to check for null, you will normally get a NullPointerException immediately afterwards, which is usually a pretty easy bug to fix. This fail fast approach is *much better* than having a fake return value (e.g. an empty string) which gets quietly propagated around your system, possibly corrupting data, without throwing an exception.

Finally, if you apply these rules to the two functions listed in the question:

- **FindPerson** - it would be appropriate for this function to return null if the person was not found
- **ReverseString** - seems like it would never fail to find a result if passed a string (since all strings can be reversed, including the empty string). So it should never return null. If something goes wrong (out of memory?) then it should throw an exception.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the semantics of the method. You could possibly specify, your method accepts only "Not null". In Java you can declare that using some metadata annotations:

```java
string ReverseString(@NotNull String stringToReverse)
```

You should somehow specify the return value. If you declare, you accept only NotNull values, you are bound to return empty string (if the input was empty string too).

The second case is a little bit complicated in its semantics. If this method is to return some person by it's primary key (and the person is expected to exist), better way is to throw exception.

```java
Person FindPerson(int personID)
```

If you search person by some guessed id (which seems to me odd), you would better declare that method as @Nullable.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the Null Object pattern whenever possible. It simplifies the code when calling your methods, and you don't get to read ugly code like

`if (someObject != null && someObject.someMethod () != whateverValue)`

For instance, if a method returns a collection of objects who fit some pattern, then returning an empty collection makes more sense than returning `null`, and iterating over this empty collection will have virtually no performance penalty. Another case would be a method that returns the class instance used to log data, returning a Null object rather than `null` is preferable in my opinion, as it does not force users to always check if the returned reference is `null`.

In cases where returning `null` makes sense (calling the `findPerson ()` method for example), I'd try to at least provide a method that returns if the object is present (`personExists (int personId)` for example), another example would be the `containsKey ()` method on a `Map` in Java). It makes callers' code cleaner, as you can easily see that there is a possibility that the desired object might not be available (person does not exist, key is not present in map). Constantly checking if a reference is `null` obfuscates the code in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Methods returning collections should return empty but others could return null, because for the collections it might so happen that you will have object but there are no elements in it, so the caller will validate for just size rather both.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is a difference between returning NULL, returning some empty result (e.g. the empty string or an empty list), and throwing an exception.

I normally take the following approach. I consider a function or method f(v1, ..., vn) call as the application of a function

```
f : S x T1 x ... x Tn -> T
```

where S it the "state of the world" T1, ..., Tn are the types of input parameters, and T is the return type.

I first try to define this function. If the function is **partial** (i.e. there are some input values for which it is not defined) I return NULL to signal this. This is because I want the computation to terminate normally and tell me that the function I have requested is not defined on the given inputs. Using, e.g., an empty string as return value is ambiguous because it could be that the function is defined on the inputs and the empty string is the correct result.

I think the extra check for a NULL pointer in the calling code **is necessary** because you are applying a partial function and it is the task of the called method to tell you if the function if not defined for the given input.

I prefer to use exceptions for errors that do not allow to carry out the computation (i.e. it was not possible to find any answer).

For example, suppose I have a class Customer and I want to implement a method

```java
Customer findCustomer(String customerCode)
```

to search for a customer in the application database by its code.
In this method, I would

- Return an object of class Customer if the query is successful,
- Return null if the query does not find any customer.
- Throw an exception if it is not possible to connect to the database.

The extra checks for null, e.g.

```java
Customer customer = findCustomer("...");
if (customer != null && customer.getOrders() > 0)
{
    ...
}
```

are part of the semantics of what I am doing and I would not just "skip them" in order to make the code read better. I do not think it is a good practice to simplify the semantics of the problem at hand just to simplify the code.

Of course, since the check for null occurs very often is it good if the language supports some special syntax for it.

I would also consider using the Null Object pattern (as suggested by Laf) as long as I can distinguish the null object of a class from all other objects.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what people already said about the `Maybe` type constructor:

Another big gain, apart from not risking NPEs, is the semantic one. In the functional world, where we deal with pure functions, we like to try to make functions that when applied are *exactly equivalent to their return value*. Consider the case of `String.reverse()`: This is a function that given a certain string represents the reversed version of that string. We know that this string exists, because every string can be reversed (strings are basically ordered sets of characters).

Now, what about `findCustomer(int id)`? This function represents the customer that has the given ID. This is something that may or may not exist. But remember, functions have a single return value, so you can't really say "this function returns a customer with the given ID *OR* it returns `null`.

This is my main issue both with returning `null` and returning a null object. They are misleading. `null` isn't a customer, and it isn't really "the absence of a customer" either. It's the absence of ANYTHING. It's just a typeless pointer to NOTHING. Very low-level and very ugly and very error-prone. A null object is also pretty misleading here I think. A null customer IS a customer. It's not the absence of one, it's not the customer with the ID asked for, so returning it is simply WRONG. This is NOT the customer I asked for, but still you claim you returned a customer. It has the wrong ID, clearly this is a bug. It breaks the contract suggested by the method name and signature. It requires the client code to assume things about your design, or to read documentation.

Both of these issues are solved by a `Maybe Customer`. Suddenly, we're not saying "this function represents the customer with the given ID". We're saying "this function represents the customer with the given ID *if it exists*. It's now very clear and explicit about what it does. If you ask for the customer with a non-existing ID, you will receive `Nothing`. How is this better than `null`? Not just for the NPE risk. But also because the type of `Nothing` isn't just `Maybe`. It's `Maybe Customer`. It has semantic meaning. It specifically means "the absence of a customer", indicating that such a customer doesn't exist.

Another problem with null is of course that it is ambiguous. Is it that you didn't find the customer, or was there a db connection error or am I just not allowed to see that customer?

If you have several error cases like this to handle, you could either throw exceptions for those versions or (and I prefer this way) you could return an `Either CustomerLoadError Customer`, representing either something that went wrong or the returned customer. It has all the advantages of `Maybe Customer` while also allowing you to specify what can go wrong.

The main thing I'm after is to capture the contract of the function in it's signature. Don't assume things, don't rely on fleeting conventions, be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

1) If semantic of function is that it can return nothing, caller MUST test for it, otherwise he will eg. take your money and give it to no-one.

2) Its good to make functions that semantically always return something (or throw).

With a **logger**, it make sense to return logger that does not log if no logger was defined. When returning collection, it almost never makes sense (except on "low enough level", where the collection itself is THE data, not what it contains) to return nothing, because an empty set is a set, not nothing.

With a **person** example, I would go "hibernate" way (get vs load, IIRC, but there it is complicated by proxy objects for lazy loading) of having two functions, one that returns null and second that throws.

Answer (score 0):

To me there are two cases here.  If you're returning some sort of list you should always return the list no matter what, empty if you don't have anything to put in it.

The only case where I see any debate is when you're returning a single item.  I find myself preferring to return null in case of failure in such a situation on the basis of making things fail fast.

If you return a null object and the caller needed a real object they might go ahead and try to use the null object producing unexpected behavior.  I think it's better for the routine to go boom if they forget to deal with the situation.  If something's wrong I want an exception ASAP.  You're less likely to ship a bug this way.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience it might be better to have empty objects, e.g. `Person unknownPerson = new Person();` or `UnknownPerson implements Person` Not sure though how to implement it exactly. Should it be a separate class with the same interface or add the code to the Person class. Currently I am struggling with a simple `equalsTo` method. The code looks garbage because I have to check if both parameters are null or they have value where I can call `equalsTo`. I imagine there are countless similar scenarios. So I would rather add an `isEmpty` method and allow empty parameters instead of using null. I will still have some garbage code, but it would be concentrated to the optional class. Another problem with this approach, that in some scenarios the parameter can be optional, but in other scenarios it can be mandatory. But it is easy to fix that, in the optional scenarios I use `Person` type, in the non-optional scenarios I use `KnownPerson implements Person`. At least I'll refactor my code to this after the next commit is done. It appears to be a much better experience in theory. In practice probably it will give too many new classes. So I guess there is no great solution for this, but if I check code rotting, then there is a lot of repetition currently, which means that the code is in the wrong abstraction level.

Answer (score -1):

- NULL should be returned if the application expects a data to be available but the data is not available.  For example,  a service that returns the CITY based on zipcode should return null if the city is not found. The caller can then decide to handle the null or blow up.
- Empty list should be returned if there are two possibilities. Data
  available or NO data available. For example a service that returns
  the CITY(s) if the population is greater than certain number. It can
  return a empty list if No data that satisfies the given criteria.

Answer (score -1):

Returning NULL is a **terrible design**, in object-oriented world. In a nutshell, NULL usage leads to:

- ad-hoc error handling (instead of exceptions)
- ambiguous semantic
- slow instead of fast failing
- computer thinking vs. object thinking
- mutable and incomplete objects

Check this blog post for a detailed explanation: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/13/why-null-is-bad.html